# Infopath form margins and boxes look wider in SharePoint (Google Chrome)

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

My InfoPath form in the Designer:

[image: Designer Form]

But on Sharepoint (Google Chrome) it shows up like this (with extra margins and text boxes not the right size):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit cell padding:

Left: 0 px

Right: 0 px

[image]

And ensure the field width is 100%

[image]

Comment: Hey @JoannaW_SPWX, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, it didnt work... In Infopath Filler, the form looks just fine. Do you think it may be something about working with it in the browser?